# Firestore exists() method cannot access data immediately after creation

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

**TL;DR** - I *seem* to be experiencing a lag between data being written to `Firestore` and that same data being available to the `exists()` method in my security rules.
I would love someone to, explain the issue / give me fix / suggest an alternative. Details below...

---

### Detailed Version

I have a collection of `groups` and a collection of `users`. Any ***user*** can create a ***group*** and when they do so their ID is added to a sub-collection of that ***group*** called `linkedUsers` while the new ***group*** ID is added to a sub-collection of the ***user*** called `linkedGroups`.

The idea is that after a ***group*** is created it can only be read or updated by a ***user*** who's ID is on that group's `linkedUsers` list, or who has the ***group*** ID on their `linkedGroups` list.

I have this set up - groups and sub-collections are created as expected and all looks fine. I have an `onSnapshot()` listener maintaining a list of all *my* groups from `users/{myUid}/linkedGroups`. Access here is granted by the simple rule...

```
match /users/{user}{
   allow read, write: if user = request.auth.uid;
}
```

I can also navigate to a new page that retrieves all the details of a specific ***group***. Here I have a rule to allow access to a group if the requesting user's ID is in that group's `linkedUsers` sub-collection...

```
match /groups/{group}{
   allow read, write:if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(group)/linkedUsers/$(request.auth.uid));
}
```

This also seems to work fine but here is the issue. When a new group is created I want to immediately navigate to a detail page for that new group. I have a listener set up that fires when the group data has (apparently) been written, and I then go to the detail page. **This works about 50% of the time** but the other 50% I get a ***`Missing or insufficient permissions`*** error. If I refresh the screen or even just wait a second or two then I can manually launch the detail page fine.

It all feels like there is a lag between the data being written to the backend and it becoming available to the `exists()` method in the security rules.

- Has anyone else come across this or similar?
- Am I going about this in some wrong way or coming to the wrong 
  conclusion?
- Is this a bug in Firestore (it is still in Beta after all)?
- And most importantly, can anyone suggest a way to get round this by 
  hack, bodge or any other means?

All these questions and more answered below (I really, really hope!)

Thanks all